# how can i shift focus to the Object Browser Search box

Tags: visual-studio, search, objectbrowser

I'm trying to divorce myself from my mouse in order to become more product and in order to do this I must find key-combos for common operations.

Every time I launch the object browser in VS, the focus is on the tree of namespaces and classes.

**How can I shift this focus to the search box?**

Better yet: **How can I launch the Object browser focused on the search box** so that I can input my search criteria?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ctrl+k, r is the keyboard shortcut once the object browser is up.

Comment: Even better, it appears to work even when the object browser isn't already up.